# How can I issue a command on my local machine from within an SSH session?

Tags: macos, ssh, shell, macbook

### Example use case:

1. I am working on my laptop running Mac OS X (**A**) and am logged into my development server (**B**) via SSH.
2. I have a script which will generate a GitHub URL for the file/branch I currently have open in my editor on (**B**).
3. I would like to open that URL in a browser on my laptop (**A**).

Other use cases might include:

- Refresh my browser every time I save a file
- Play a song locally when I issue a [git command](https://gist.github.com/dfm/5828028)
- Open a Jira ticket corresponding to the branch I have checked out.

Comment: SSH not like, for example, `ftp` or `windbg`, where you can escape with something like a `!` and means its a local command (and not a remote command). Just open a second terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of SSH reverse tunnel. It works like this; do this on the machine you are using here, `remote_server` is the name of the remote server:

```
ssh -R 13000:localhost:22 remote_server
```

And display in image on your `local machine` from the `remote server`:

```
ssh <USERNAME>@localhost -p 13000 "DISPLAY=:0 ristretto <IMAGE>"
```

**EDIT**: There may be not X server installed on Mac OS machine, I don't use it but the general idea stays the same. The advantage of using reverse tunneling is that your local machine does not have to have a public IP address.

Comment: Some folks at work are discussing the security implications of this. Would you care to add some notes about what additional risks I may or may not be taking by using this approach?

Comment: SSH reverse tunneling is very dangerous in the sense that it can be used to bypass many firewalls: http://toic.org/blog/2009/reverse-ssh-port-forwarding/. As with everything it can be used for good and bad things. If the server you are connecting to is used by many people you don't want to use a public key authentication because anybody who knows your username and hostname/IP can access your machine because they can see a port number you chose in `netstat` output.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant way to approach this, but—since you are using Mac OS X—the only thing I can think of if you are already remoted into the other machine is to issue an SSH command back to your host like this. The big prerequisite is you would need to have your SSH server up and running on your Mac OS X laptop and make sure your router’s firewall rules allow for SSH connections on port 22 for this to work.

So let’s assume your laptop is named `machineA` and you wanted to open a URL like `http://google.com` from the remote machine (**B**) then you would just issue this SSH command on machine **B**.

```
ssh username@machineA 'open http://google.com'
```

That would initiate an SSH connected back to your local machine and run the command `open http://google.com` which would open up a browser window—based on your default browser—that will go to the URL that was passed to it; `http://google.com`.